# understanding classes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, class

I am just working my way trough classes working on a project in vb.net
there's something that I can't figure out.

In my code I have this class (you don't need to read it, it just copies files from path A to B):

```
Public Class FileCopyExample

    Public Sub New()
        Dim progressForm As New ProgressForm()
        progressForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Public Async Function CopyFolderContentsAsync(sourceFolder As String, destinationFolder As String) As Task
        
        If Not Directory.Exists(sourceFolder) Then
            Throw New DirectoryNotFoundException($"Source folder '{sourceFolder}' not found.")
        End If

        If Not Directory.Exists(destinationFolder) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder)
        End If

        Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder)
        Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)()

        For Each file In files
            Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(file)
            Dim destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fileName)
            tasks.Add(CopyFileAsync(file, destinationFilePath))
        Next

        Dim subFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder)
        For Each subFolder In subFolders
            Dim folderName = Path.GetFileName(subFolder)
            Dim destinationSubFolder = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, folderName)
            tasks.Add(CopyFolderContentsAsync(subFolder, destinationSubFolder))
        Next

        Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
    End Function

    Private Async Function CopyFileAsync(sourcePath As String, destinationPath As String) As Task
        Using sourceStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(sourcePath)
            Using destinationStream As FileStream = File.Create(destinationPath)
                Await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

End Class
```

What I want to do is open a form with a little ProgressBar object to show the advancement of the file transfer procedure.

So I created another class that opens a form and adds a progressBar on it.

```
Public Class ProgressForm
    Inherits Form

    Public progressBar As New ProgressBar()
    Public startButton As New Button()

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponents()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeComponents()
        Me.Text = "Progress Form"
        Me.Size = New Size(300, 150)

        progressBar.Minimum = 0
        progressBar.Maximum = 100
        progressBar.Value = 0
        Me.Controls.Add(progressBar)
        Me.Controls.Add(startButton)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now if I want ProgressBar to work I will need to reference the object ProgressBar from (inside) my other class (FileCopyExample) but If I try to do so I receive the error

> Error  BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

I tried to declare ProgressBar as public but it didn't work. Can anyone explain me where is the issue?

Comment: *"I will need to reference the object ProgressBar from (inside) my other class"*. No, you absolutely do not and should not need to do that. What you should do is have your class expose the progress of the operation publicly, so anyone who wants to listen for it can get it, then each listener can do whatever is appropriate with that information. If you tie your class to that one specific `progressBar` then it's useless for anything else. The most likely way to accomplish that is via an event.

Answer (score 1):

You have good theoretical understanding about what and how should happen, but the detail you stumbled into is the fact that Visual Basic is case-insensitive, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc40055

[image]

so, let's use the information we have just discussed while pondering about this line:

```
Public progressBar As New ProgressBar()
```

With a case-insensitive mindset, we quickly observe that `progressBar` is the same as `ProgressBar`, save for the difference between p and P, which does not matter in Visual Basic. You should try changing the name of your `progressBar` to something else along with references to it, because now your project believes that you try to use `Shared` (class-level) properties and since they are object-level, it fails to do so, even though you used the correct case, it did not matter in this case-insensitive environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a Show() method of your ProgressForm class, but the class, does not have a Show() method as shown in your code:

```
Dim progressForm As New ProgressForm()
progressForm.Show()
```

If you're trying to call a Show() method of ProgressBar(), you must refer to your instance of ProgressBar(), which is your public variable progressBar.

Change your code to refer to progressBar like this:

```
progressForm.progressBar.Show()
```